# How to use mock in django?

Tags: python, django, mocking, virtualenv

I tried to install a mock library for django from http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/

But when i type in

```
pip install -U mock
```

while in virtualenv, and then try to

```
import mock
```

from django project's shell i get:

```
ImportError: No module named mock
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 4):

Check to see if the module is in the path. To do this, in the Python shell:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
```

If it was installed correctly, you should see the `mock` directory in one of the directories printed out.

If you do not find the `mock` directory, I'm assuming that `pip` is not installing the module in the `virtualenv` packages directory.

Comment: pip install package 'flat' to site-packages directory so you won't see it in sys.path.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something but even flat packages should be seen in `sys.path` no? Please elaborate.

Comment: sys.path only show search paths, not the module path. So if pip install mock to let say `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages` then this what you see in sys.path. Not `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mock`. Easy install install each package into dedicated folder so it has to add that folder to sys.path and you can see mock-x.x such as `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mock-0.8.0beta4-py2.6.egg`.

Comment: Ah, yes. I understood that. My answer didn't explain that. My apologies. Seems like @santino resolved his/her issue so all good.

Answer (score 2):

OK, it was my fault.

I ran shell and tests by:

```
./manage.py
```

instead of

```
python manage
```

so my virtualenv directory wasn't included in sys.path, and mock package was unavaible. Thanks for help.